# ajax-retrieved-value different in .load() and .on() alerts

Tags: jquery

I have this function to load data into `#container`, after clicking on the `li`.

**HTML**

```
<li onclick="$(document).ShowPosts(4)"></li>
<div class="more">[show posts]</div>

   <div id="container"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery.fn.ShowPosts = function(id_user) {

 var total_posts=999999999;

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "total_posts.php",
     data: {
       'id_user': id_user
     },
     success: function(data) {
       var total_posts = data;
     });

    //load first group      
    $("#container").load(url_load,{id_user':id_user}, 
   function(){ alert(total_posts); /*shows up 9999999;*/
  });                


   $(".more").on('click', function(e) {
       alert(total_posts); /*shows up retrieved by ajax - correct;*/
     }
   });

}
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem is that after the first load `.load()`, within the `load() function(){}` the alert shows up `total_posts as 9999999` (predefined value) when would have to be `the retrieved by ajax total_posts.php`

but in the `.on()` when clicking on `.more`  the alert shows up correctly the value of `total_posts`.

Why does an alert shows up incorrect and correct values within the main function?

Comment: The A(Asynchronous) in AJAX means control does not wait for a response to before executing the statement(s) that follow. Therefore, `.load()` will execute before a response is received.

Comment: and why an alert shows up correct and the other one incorrect values?

Comment: You have a global variable `total_posts` (which is not a good idea). By the time you click `.more` the ajax response has been received and the success callback has set that variable to the desired value. **If you happen to click before a response is received, you'll not get the desired value**

Comment: I understand... how do I fix this?

Comment: See answer below. For more information see related question.

Comment: thank you. I have this last question...Is this the only way to fix this?....I thought something like `.on("load",...` delegate...or something like that...I dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will ensure that you get the correct value by not executing `.load()` until an ajax response is received.

```
success: function(data) {
    var total_posts = data;
    //load first group      
     $("#container").load(url_load,{id_user:id_user}, function(){ 
         alert(total_posts); /*shows up 9999999;*/
     });
 });
```

**NOTE:** Do not unnecessarily clutter the global scope.

Comment: It solved my question.  I have this other question, maybe you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49287670/9485263  thank you.